# How can I have a data dictionary and how it works?

Tags: postgresql, translation, primary-key

I have to create a table in my database in order to implement multilanguage in my application to achieve this I create a table :

```
translation_table{
    EN ,
    FR ,
    ES
}
```

English will be our default language. But in this case I don't know how I can implement it on my application.

So I want do to something like this :

```
translation_table{
    Elt_name,
    EN ,
    FR ,
    ES
}
```

Which one is the best to do ?

Moreover, the user of the application will have the possibity to modify the default language he wants to use. (I would like to create a new column but I don't know what to put in this column). Maybe I have to create an other table to link them.

I don't really understand how in my application **(I work with Angular for my front end and I work with .Net Core for my back end)** I can have this and how can I use it.

Comment: What you describe isn't what a *data dictionary* is. A "data dictionary" is a piece of documentation that describes to humans what data elements are, their constraints etc. For example "RETIREMENT_AGE, integer, optional, The age in years at which the applicant plans to retire."

Comment: This is not clear & if it were clear then it would be too broad. Please tell us exactly what you are supposed to produce, what you were given & what have you done & ask one specific question about where & how you are stuck & what you researched about getting unstuck. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please quote your assignment. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one thing you have to keep in mind(first point),

1. if in you application the default language for all the user will be
   English, then you shouldn't use #EN column as primary key if used that one it will through an  #ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint while you insert data.
2. Write a SQL statement of default insert value for column #EN for all user inputs as English in your .NET program.
3. if you what you can add a user name with primary key and it will primary key.
4. Example,

```
create table data_dictionary(
    User_name text primary key
    EN text ,
    FR text,
    ES text
)
```

first update:

```
insert into data_dictionary(user_name,en,fr,es) 
values ('A',eng','french','Z')
```

Second update

```
insert into data_dictionary(user_name,en,fr,es) 
values ('B',eng','y','X')
```

third update

```
insert into data_dictionary(user_name,en,fr,es) 
values ('c',eng','ab','xy')
```

and so on........